# babel-node throw error for react.jsx file

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I get a babel-node error.  Please help me in fixing this issue.

Please see the error below

```
enter code here
 root@ip-10-252-14-11:/home/ubuntu/workarea/sourcecode/ntdl# babel-node 
 node/react-render.jsx
```

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/template/lib/builder.js:86
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Unknown substitution "BODY" given
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/template/lib/populate.js:22:15
    at Array.forEach ()
    at populatePlaceholders (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/template/lib/populate.js:20:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/template/lib/string.js:20:51
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/template/lib/builder.js:83:14
    at spec (/home/ubuntu/workarea/sourcecode/ntdl/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of/lib/index.js:159:20)
    at PluginPass.ForOfStatement (/home/ubuntu/workarea/sourcecode/ntdl/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of/lib/index.js:72:21)
    at newFn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:223:21)
    at NodePath._call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:64:19)
    at NodePath.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:38:17)
    =============
    at exports.default (/home/ubuntu/workarea/sourcecode/ntdl/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of/lib/index.js:11:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js:167:14
    at cachedFunction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:40:17)
    at loadPluginDescriptor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js:202:28)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js:59:16
    at Array.map ()
    at recurseDescriptors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js:58:36)
    at recurseDescriptors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js:92:27)

my  babel-node version is

root@ip-10-252-14-11:/home/ubuntu/workarea/sourcecode/ntdl# babel-node --version
7.0.0-beta.40

my package.json file contents is

```
{
  "name": "ntdl",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "Build and rendering server for NTDL django project",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN license.txt",
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
  "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
  "eslint": "^3.11.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.8.0",
  "uglify": "^0.1.5"
  },
 "scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently --no-color \"npm run pack\" \"npm run django\"  
  \"npm run render\"",
  "partial-start": "concurrently --no-color \"npm run pack\" \"npm run 
  render\"",
  "start-prod": "concurrently --no-color \"uwsgi --ini 
  /home/ntdl/code/uwsgi.ini\" \"nginx\" \"npm run render-prod\"",
  "pack": "webpack --watch --config node/webpack/webpack.config.js",
  "pack-prod": "webpack --config node/webpack/webpack.production.config.js",
  "django": "python manage.py runserver",
  "render": "babel-node node/react-render.jsx --watch",
  "render-prod": "babel-node node/react-render.jsx",
  "pylint": "pylint ntdl cms search",
  "eslint": "eslint static/style/style.js && eslint --ext .jsx search",
  "lint": "npm run pylint && npm run eslint",
  "es-index": "babel-node elasticsearch/index/create.js",
  "migratedb": "python manage.py migrate"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "autobind-decorator": "^2.1.0",
  "babel-cli": "^7.0.0-alpha.20",
  "babel-core": "^7.0.0-alpha.20",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
  "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.4",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-alpha.20",
  "babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0-alpha.20",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^2.0.0-alpha.20",
  "babel-preset-react": "^7.0.0-alpha.20",
  "babel-register": "^7.0.0-alpha.20",
  "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
  "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
  "elasticsearch": "^12.1.3",
  "express": "^4.15.4",
  "history": "^4.7.2",
  "material-ui": "^0.16.7",
  "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
  "openseadragon": "^2.3.0",
  "pdfjs-dist": "^1.8.492",
  "query-string": "^5.0.0",
  "react": "^15.6.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
  "react-render": "^1.2.1",
  "react-router": "^4.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
  "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
  "redux": "^3.7.2",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
  "request": "2.79.0",
  "webpack": "^3.5.5",
  "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.1.0",
  "yargs": "^6.6.0"
 } 
 }
```

my .babelrc file contents are

```
{
  "presets": [
  "react",
  ["env", {
  "targets": {
    "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 11"],
    "node": "current"
  }
  }]
],

"plugins": [
  "transform-decorators-legacy",
  "transform-optional-chaining",/
  "transform-object-rest-spread"
 ]
}
```

Please tell me how to resolve this error.  and guide me the best practices for using babel

What is the difference between babel-core vs @babel/core?   Please through some light over it.

With Many Thanks,

Bharath AK

Comment: Why did you get this error, what were you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Paul,  To make the application run I have to call npm run render and and on another putty window I will python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  When I run npm run render I get this error.  Npm run render does babel-node node/react-render.jsx.  Could you please explain difference between babel-core and @babel/core? It is a wagtail application inside which react application is part of this wagtail application

Comment: It was developed by previous developer.  I am currently working on this.  It was working earlier.  I dont know what went wrong or do I miss anything

Comment: So you are trying to run the application? have you updated babel? or react?

Comment: previous developer machine is returned I got this new machine.  I had done npm install, It is fresh machine, I had clone the source code from git and install many packages. It is ubuntu machine on aws.

Comment: I had done npm install for installing packages.   Dockers are used for deployment

Comment: i had installed npm i --save-dev babel-core babel-register babel-cli and also npm i --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/register  and npm i --save-dev @babel-core/register Still get the same error

Comment: Is there a running version of this project?

Comment: There is no running version but a deployed version from dockers is there for demo purpose.  It is not running from source code.  it is pulled from dockers to run on aws

Comment: Please suggest any idea.  I am struggling to make this run from source code for many days

Comment: I had removed the node_modules completely, and got the old package.json and babelrc file and reactrender.jsx file from git and done npm install.  Still i get issues.

Comment: I had done npm uninstall -g @babel/core @babel-core/register @babel/cli babel-core babel-loader babel-register.  now I get Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'

Comment: One way is to edit `package.json` to use newest versions for all babel related packages, it should make the project able to build, with the price that you may need to adjust a few outdated configs/codes. Still not too bad compared to being stuck with this error here IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try and delete `package-lock.json`, then run `npm update`

Try an install babel-core using `npm install --save-dev babel-core`

Comment: Hi paul, I get the following error module.js:559
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:557:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:484:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/node/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:19:37)

Comment: module.js:559
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:557:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:484:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/node/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:19:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)

Comment: it is refenceing  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/node/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:19:37)

Comment: Hi Paul, I had followed the same steps  I had removed package-lock.json and then ran npm update and npm install --save-dev babel-core  then I get the same error

Comment: it is reference the global path module.js:559
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:557:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:484:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/node/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:19:37)  do I have install anything globally

Comment: I had also tried  npm install --save-dev babel-core -g still I get the same error.

Comment: Hi All,  I am able to update babel-core both globally and locally with npm install.  After updating I get the same error as first /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/template/lib/builder.js:86 throw err; ^

Error: Unknown substitution "BODY" given at  Please help me in resolving this error

Comment: Hi All, I had changed all babel-packages to same version on dev dependcies to point to 7.0.0-beta.3  still I get the same error.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you for your help.  The problem is resolved now.  I had changed all babel packages to same version.  I had changed the babel-node version in match with the other babel-plugins.  Then run babel-node.  all the errors vanished. secondly I had removed ^ in package.json for babel version's for eg to install bebel-register@^7.0.0-alpha.20 I had removed ^ before 7.0.0 I had installed the exact same version.  All the errors had gone.  Thank you some all.  With Many thanks, Bharath AK